# mysqli using prepare

Tags: php, mysql, object, mysqli

I need some help, I have created this function and it works fine, but now I need to use "prepare" in MySQLi.  Can I get some help?

I have tried http://dk.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php but I don't really understand how to prepare work with MySQLi.

My db obj is `( $this->db )` in my class.

I need a sample of my own code here, and if I want to insert/delete and update data. :)

Thanks a lot to all.

```
public function query( $sql , $multi = false )
    {
        // if query is ok
        if ( $q = $this->db->query( $sql ) ) 
        {
            if ( $multi == true )
            {
                // multi fetch make in array/object
                while( $d = $q->fetch_object() )
                {
                    $obj[] = $d;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // single fetch
                $obj = $q->fetch_object();
            }
            return $obj;
        }
        // if query fail print error
        else
        {
            echo $this->db->error;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to comment your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$mysqli = new mysql("host", "user", "password", "location");
$statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID=?");
$statement->bind_param("s","5");
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->result_metadata;
$object = $result->fetch_object();
```

Basically, you put where you want values to go with a `?`, and then bind them in. The S in the beginning I belive means string.

To find out more about preparing stuff, look at the [MYSQLi Documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: How can i soe after execute make "fetch_object" ? i have problems whiat that :/

Comment: Well, I gave you the first part, the second part someone else should be able to solve. I'm just getting a headache thinking about it. Its called bad API design.

Comment: Tanks Chacha102, you samlpe its relly use ful, bot i online need now to how i can select it out to e.g. foreach( $obj AS $value ) right now. if you can help me here i accept you answer :)